# Connecting a Ubuntu Server to a VPN

Tags: server, vpn, openvpn

I have a Digital Ocean Droplet - Linux based running a Ubuntu Server. I am wondering could anyone recommend or explain the correct way to connect to a VPN in order to access an API. I am building a web application on this server and looking to access API to gain information to display on web app. I have looked in to OpenVPN but do not want to use this. Can anyone recommend good tutorials on how to do this?

Comment: "I have looked in to OpenVPN but do not want to use this" That is used to use your server as a vpn. You would need a (openvpn) client. "Can anyone recommend good tutorials on how to do this?" https://askubuntu.com/questions/162167/how-do-i-create-a-vpn-connection-using-only-the-terminal-ssh will still work.

Comment: The VPN is being created my my client.. I am just looking to connect to it via my Ubuntu server

Comment: See the link. pppd is what you need.  That is what lets your server (being the client) connect to a vpn server.

Comment: @Rinzwind thank you for your reply. Further to this, can you connect to another vpn connection using open vpn or is open vpn just to set up a vpn connect?

Comment: OpenVPN is a server that lets you connect to the machine where OpenVPN runs. A VPN client can connect to such a server. That does not need to be OpenVPN client; Remmina is the default client, but you could also use a Cisco or fortinet client. And you can have both installed on 1 machine too: openvpn server and one or more clients (to connect to other servers)